# Can I position a TextView based on center position of another TextView?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have 3 initial TextViews at the top (TextView1, TextView2, TextView3). Then I have a TextView as a label that expands across the whole width of the screen. Below that label I have 3 more TextViews which I wish to position at the horizontal centre of the top 3 TextViews'. Is there something I can put in the xml to achieve this? I could not find any appropriate constraints. All I could find was centre horizontal parent. Here is a picture example what I want it to look like:

http://i57.tinypic.com/21zq03.png

I am using relative layout.

Comment: Do you need another three TextView's under the same position of above?

Comment: Yes, the numbers below the label have to be positioned with their corresponding upper text views' centre positions.

Comment: You can use horizontal Linearlayout with three TextView's applying weight to all three TextView's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use layout_gravity -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/huge_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numtext1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numtext2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numtext3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How can this determine the top TextView I want to get centre position of though? There are 3.

Comment: IF you set layout gravity of each textview center_horizontal i think you will get result..try it.Post you xml code also